# Chart js - Legend hidden when create chart after document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, chart.js

I'm actually developing one app using the javascript plugin chartjs (on the framework Symfony 3) and I realised that when we create a chart before the page it's ready, the legend it's correctly shown, but when I create other chart doing click on a button (after document.ready) the legend it's hidden.

To illustrate my problem, when I do :

```
// the chart is draw with the legend
drawChart();

// The chart is draw without the legend
$(document).ready(function() {
  drawChart();
});
```

Have you ever meet this problem ? Is there a solution to solve this ?

Big thanks to all who takes time to help me !